# Using C# and REST with Google Sheets API

Tags: c#, rest, google-sheets-api

The documentation for using the C# library to do create, read, and update for Google Sheets is very sparse and although I have successfully used samples I'm having difficulty in implementing other operations (e.g. deleting and renaming sheets in a spreadsheet).

The documentation of the REST calls appears to be much easier to follow.  The only problem for me is to combine the authentication with something like an HttpRequest.

It would then be easy to create the request URL (as shown in the documentation) and to build or read json in the body of the request or response.  (using json2csharp.com to create C# objects from the json definitions in the documentation)

The code for getting authentication using the C# library works without a problem (shown below).  How can I adapt this to authenticate an HttpRequest ?

```
       UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/Access.json");
            var loaded = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream);
            var secrets = loaded.Secrets;
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

        }

        // Create Google Sheets API service.
        var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });
```

Comment: Which documentation are you looking at?  I'm finding some useful quickstarts here:  https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet  along with the full API reference here:  https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/

Comment: Please indent your code correctly

Comment: I have used the two references shown developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet
 was used to create the code I posted.  The second shows how to make specific Http requests with a json body and/or return, and that is what I want to do. 
developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest 
The question is how to authenticate such a request in C# 

As far as the indentation of my code is concerned, I let ReSharper use its default formatting.